# xceed.wpf.toolkit ColorPicker XAMLparseException error in windows server 2008

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception, xceed

I  am using xceed.wpf.toolkit version 1.9.0 on a wpf project. it causes a xamlParseException when trying to load the colorPicker.

This is my xaml:

```
<Viewbox Margin="3">
    <Xceed:ColorPicker Name="BtFontColor" Width="30"
                       SelectedColorChanged="FontColorSelectedColorChanged"
                       ToolTip="Font Color" />
</Viewbox>
```

And the exception is:

> {"'Initialization of 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorPicker' threw an exception.' Line number '121' and line position '48'."}

The inner exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.classic, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)":"Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.classic, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4"}

When I remove that XAML portion everything works fine.

This problem seems to occur only on machines running Windows Server 2008 R2, I tried it on various other windows OS's and I dont get that error.

My dll is in the correct place and the path is referenced correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4. [Here link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

I solve b